# Can't print jQuery's Tablesorter with lines. lines are missing when I print

Tags: tablesorter

When I print Tablesorter from an HTML page, the lines don't show up.  Can anyone explain to me a possible fix?

Comment: Did you try checking "print background images?"

Comment: Is this a script on the client side or you're referring to the print settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the lines and don't care about the colored background, then add this to your print stylesheet:

```
@media print {
    table.tablesorter th, table.tablesorter td {
        border: #000 1px solid;
    }
}
```

If you do want the background color, then do as @Matt Ball recommends, and set the browser to print background images... File > Page Setup (for Firefox for Windows); For Chrome, print (Ctrl-P) then set it to print in color, etc.